# How to make SDK my code safe from other developers when i give them AAR file in Android?

Tags: android, sdk, android-manifest

I am creating one SDK for android which include the Activity, Services and Broadcast receivers.

Problem is when i generate the AAR file from my project and import it to other sample project my All the Activity, Services and Receivers names are visible from Manifest of my AAR file.

I don't want to expose any of my class name to users of My AAR file, Please provide proper way to hide my confidential code and classes.

Comment: were you able to resolve this statement? Now, I have same problem. Need to obfuscate the AAR code. Please help me if you were able to resolve issue

Answer (score 1):

Remember one thing "Everything is hackable" and java classes are decompilabel.
You can use the Proguard to Obfuscate your code

Have a look
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

With Proguard, it will also shrink your code and reduces the size of you AAR file
and change the names of the classes, then it is hard to recognize the functionality of your lib file.

Learn more about Obfuscation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)